# Conditional density and variance of Nadaraya-Watson model

Tags: conditional-probability, kernel-smoothing

Given $N$ data points $x$ and $N$ targets $t$, considering a new point $x$ and the corresponding new target $t$, what would be:

- The conditional density
- The conditional mean
- variance

of the Nadaraya-Watson model

$$p(x,t) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^Nf(x - x_t, t - t_n)$$

Where the kernel is an isotropic Gaussian with mean $(0,0)$ and covariance is $\sigma^2I$, in terms of $k(x, x_n)$?

How do you verify that the sum of the functions = 1, since it is a distribution?

Comment: This can be found in any textbook on nonparametric econometrics; see [Li & Racine (2006)](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8355.html), for example.

Comment: What is your observation? X? And you're doing an inference about the variable $t$, is it right? Please make this clear.

Comment: A nice introduction to the Nadaraya-Watson estimator can be found through Bruce Hansen's (University of Wisconsin-Madison) online lecture notes http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/718/NonParametrics2.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have well described the conditional density (with $y$ in the place of your $t$): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_regression#Derivation

The conditional density is the $f(y|x) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f(x)}$.

The conditional mean would be the mean for that density $E(Y|X)$ and the same thing for variance $E(Y-E(Y|X)|X)$.

It is the integral of the conditional density $f(y|X)$ over all y that shall be equal to 1. That will lead you to an integral of all K functions.